# HTML_QuickForm_Controller: Unhandled action "_qf_Main_reload" in page "Main"

Tags: contribution-page

Contribution page with membership signup enabled get `HTML_QuickForm_Controller: Unhandled action "_qf_Main_reload" in page "Main"` error once the form is submitted from main page

CiviCRM : 5.35.1
CMS: Drupal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please confirm if you have CiviDiscount extension enabled and on latest 3.8.2 version?

Similar [issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/307) was recorded for CiviDiscount on gitlab.

HTH

Pradeep